# How can I listen for click on map if popup is not open with Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, mapbox

I have a pretty well functioning Map component that does what I need it to do but with one small issue.

I'm listening for click events on the map. So if you click anywhere on the map, there is an fetch call. Well, I don't want them to happen when a Popup is open.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to prevent that.

[image]

Have pretty much all of the code as follows:

#### Map.vue

```
<template>
    <AVPage>
        <div style="height: 85vh">
            <MapboxMap
                style="height: 100%"
                :accessToken="mapboxToken"
                :mapStyle="mapboxStyle"
                @mb-click="map.getGeocodeData($event)"
                @mb-created="
                    (instance) => map.setInstance(instance, mapboxToken)
                "
            >
                <MapboxGeolocateControl position="bottom-right" />
                <MapboxMarker
                    v-for="(result, index) in map?.locations"
                    :lng-lat="[result.location[0], result.location[1]]"
                    :key="index"
                    popup
                    icon="bar"
                >
                    <template v-slot:popup>
                        <LocationCard :location="result" :map="map" />
                    </template>
                </MapboxMarker>
                <MapboxNavigationControl position="bottom-right" />
                <MapboxPopup
                    v-if="Object.keys(map.poi).length"
                    :lng-lat="[
                        map.poi.geometry.location.lng,
                        map.poi.geometry.location.lat
                    ]"
                    @mb-open="() => map.popupOpen = true"
                    @mb-close="map.clearPoi()"
                >
                    <LocationCard :location="map.poi" :map="map" />
                </MapboxPopup>
            </MapboxMap>
        </div>
    </AVPage>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from "vue"
import "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/lib/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css"
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css"
import {
    MapboxMap,
    MapboxMarker,
    MapboxPopup,
    MapboxNavigationControl,
    MapboxGeolocateControl
} from "@studiometa/vue-mapbox-gl"
import LocationCard from "./components/LocationCard.vue"
import Map from "src/pinia/models/Map.js"

const map = ref(new Map(0, 0))

const mapboxToken = computed(() => process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN)
const mapboxStyle = computed(() => process.env.MAPBOX_STYLE)
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.mapboxgl-popup-content {
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

#### Map.js

```
import { api } from "src/boot/axios.js"
import { buildQueryString } from "src/helpers.js"
import Model from "./Model"

class Map extends Model {
    instance = null
    token = null

    lat = null
    lng = null

    locations = []
    poi = {}

    fetching = true
    popupOpen = false

    constructor(lat, lng) {
        super()

        this.lat = lat
        this.lng = lng
    }

    clearPoi() {
        this.poi = {}
    }

    setInstance(instance, token) {
        this.instance = instance
        this.token = token
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (data) => this.successCallback(data),
            (error) => this.errorCallback(error)
        )
    }

    async getLocations() {
        const { data } = await api.get(
            `/pet-places?lat=${this.lat}&lng=${this.lng}`
        )

        data.data.forEach((item) => {
            this.locations.push(item)
        })

        this.instance.flyTo({
            center: [this.lng, this.lat],
            zoom: 15
        })

        this.fetching = false
    }

    async postRating(lat, lng, name, rating) {
        const { data } = await api.post("/pet-places", {
            lat,
            lng,
            name,
            rating
        })

        data.data.forEach((location) => {
            this.locations.push(location)
        })
    }

    async successCallback({ coords }) {
        const { latitude, longitude } = coords
        this.lat = latitude
        this.lng = longitude

        this.getLocations()
    }

    errorCallback(err) {
        console.log("error", err)
    }

    async getGeocodeData(e) {
        if (this.fetching || Object?.keys(this?.poi)?.length) return

        try {
            this.fetching = true
            const { lngLat, originalEvent } = e

            if (originalEvent.target.tagName !== "CANVAS") {
                return
            } else {
                if (this.popupOpen) {
                    this.popupOpen = false
                    return
                }
            }

            const { lng, lat } = lngLat

            const queryString = {
                access_token: this.token,
                type: "poi"
            }

            const response = await fetch(
                `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${lng},${lat}.json${buildQueryString(
                    queryString
                )}`,
                { method: "GET" }
            )

            const results = await response.json()

            const { features } = results

            const poi = features.find(
                (feature) =>
                    feature.id.includes("poi") || feature.id.includes("address")
            )

            if (!poi) {
                return
            }

            const { data } = await api.get(
                `/location/places?coordinates=${lat},${lng}`
            )
            const { results: locations } = data.data

            this.poi = locations[0] ?? {}
        } finally {
            this.fetching = false
        }
    }
}

export default Map
```

EDIT: Got it to work, but I feel that it isn't the best way...

Add a boolean that 'watches' for the state of popup on the page.
If it is true, and the click was on the canvas, then don't perform the API request.